# search specific node into an xml file

Tags: php, html, xml, session

I've made this xml file to manage some audio tracks information.

```
<releases>
<track>
<uid>betauser</uid>
<artist>cianci</artist>
<title>cianci</title>
<year>2001</year>
<label>duib</label>
<cover>DSC_0115.jpg</cover>
<aside>chitarra_peps</aside>
<bside>chitarra_peps</bside>
</track>
</releases>
```

It's updated by users that will input all the information about tracks using a form. I need to search into the xml to show to the logged user his inserted tracks, so i want to use the $_SESSION variable to search into the xml file and return only the nodes added by the user. Is it possible using php? I store the $_SESSION information into the field named uid, so this value is different for every user.

Comment: Sure. You can use something like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) to read the XML file. You could loop through it, then show the user only the `<track>` entries that contain a `<uid>` with the same value as whatever's in the session.

Comment: *I store the $_SESSION information into the field named uid* show an example

Comment: @splash58 here is the code.. this solution is implemented in another php page that manage the writing of the xml. here is an example for you

$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('uid', $_POST['user_id'])); // i use this to write into the xml the $_SESSION data.
in another page that calls the script when the form is submitted, i used this code to assign the $_SESSION data to a form field:
<div class="form-group">
<input id="huid" name="user_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>"class="form-control input-md">
                               </div>

Comment: @rickdenhaan, can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SimpleXml and Xpath  to find track with specified uid

```
$uid = 'betauser';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$track = $xml->xpath('//track[uid="'. $uid .'"]');
echo $track[0]->asXML();
```

**[demo](https://eval.in/785817)**

Comment: If i set the $uid variable to the $_SESSION it will work anymore?

$uid = $_SESSION['username']

Comment: of course. Only it should be the same value that was used when xml was being made

Comment: So only the user with the betauser username can view the results? this will affect the script generally or it will work also for other username?

Comment: If you, when producing xml, write uid of any user then use my xpath and giving it the same  uid,  you will received tracks of that user

Comment: whit this line, echo $track[0]->asXML();  i suppose the script extract the information..right? i've tried the code and it works great, but show only one result and i've added more entries with the same test user.. any idea on what's wrong?

Comment: I've solved using your code, thank you! With a little modification works well.. 

$uid = $_SESSION['username'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file("../tracks.xml");
$track = $xml->xpath('//track[uid="'. $uid .'"]');
        foreach($track as $tracks)
  {
 $artistname = $tracks->artist;
 $tracktitle = $tracks->title;
 $relyear = $tracks->year;
 $label = $tracks->label;
 $coverfile = $tracks->cover;
?>

Comment: Yes, yuo did rigtht. Good luck!